# A single point moving at different speeds through different regions on a plot (Manipulate)

Tags: manipulate, animation

I've been working on this for a while with little success. I have a point (that needs to be connected to a `Manipulate` control in some way), that moves up the plot and should appear to move at a different speed in each region.

I was using `Trigger` with `AnimationRunning`, and setting the `AnimationRate` for each (each "region" got its own `Control`/`Trigger`) but it doesn't work properly every time.

The point should follow the path of the dashed arrow and the speed it should move at in each region is labeled above the plot.

[image]

For some reason I cannot figure this out. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the basic idea, where you can adjust the function, limits, and `Piecewise` arguments for your specific case.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{120 - 50 x^2, 120 - 50 Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {70, 120},
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue},
  FillingStyle -> LightGray,
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], 
    Point[{.5, 
      Piecewise[{{73 a + 70, 0 <= a < .2}, 
                 {13.77 a + 81.85, .2 <= a < 1.9}, 
                 {120 a - 120, 1.9 <= a < 2} }]}]}],
 {{a, 1, " "}, 0, 2, VerticalSlider, ControlPlacement -> Left}]
```

[image]